# Why aren't in-addr.arpa addresses resolvable?

Tags: networking, dns

Python on my Mac thinks my fully qualified domain name is `1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa`. That seems like a tautologically true reverse DNS response for a system that doesn't actually have a real domain name. But for some reason that domain can't be resolved forward to the IP it clearly represents (`127.0.0.1`):

```
$ python -i
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getfqdn()
'1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa'
>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
>>>
```

It's not just Python; I can't ping `1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa` either, due to a DNS resolution failure.

Why are `in-addr.arpa` domains not resolvable to the IPs they represent?

Comment: Could be wrong about this but it's probably because they aren't intended to map to IP addresses. They are intended to map to domain names. You already have the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

127.in-addr.arpa. has not been delegated to any public name servers by IANA, as it's a reserved IP block for loopback addresses.

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin% nslookup
> set type=SOA
> in-addr.arpa.
Server:     192.168.2.1
Address:    192.168.2.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
in-addr.arpa
    origin = b.in-addr-servers.arpa
    mail addr = nstld.iana.org
    serial = 2017043116
    refresh = 1800
    retry = 900
    expire = 604800
    minimum = 3600

Authoritative answers can be found from:
in-addr.arpa    nameserver = a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa    nameserver = b.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa    nameserver = c.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa    nameserver = d.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa    nameserver = e.in-addr-servers.arpa.
in-addr.arpa    nameserver = f.in-addr-servers.arpa.
> server a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
Default server: a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
Address: 199.212.0.73#53
> 127.in-addr.arpa.
Server:     a.in-addr-servers.arpa.
Address:    199.212.0.73#53

** server can't find 127.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
>
```

That is an authoritative 'no such domain' response.

I guess you could put a host entry:

`1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa.   127.0.0.1`

in `/etc/hosts` or whatever local resource your system uses for an internal DNS resolver.

Comment: So is Python wrong in asserting this as a plausible FQDN for the host?

Comment: [nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin% python2.7 -i

Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr 23 2017, 15:24:58) 

[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket

>>> socket.getfqdn()

'nevin-mac-mini.local'

>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())

'192.168.2.122'

>>> socket.getfqdn()

'nevin-mac-mini-test.local'

>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())

'192.168.2.122'

>>> ^D

[nevin-mac-mini:~] nevin%

Comment: Well, comments don't format quite as well.

"nevin-mac-mini.local" is my "Computer Name" that's set in the Sharing SystemPrefs pane...  When I edited the name to append a -test, python picked it up right away.

Comment: My version of python2.7 was installed by MacPorts 2.4.1 btw.